# .htaccess doesn't escape question mark on RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, mod-rewrite

I have a website with an old type of Single Sign On. A parent website sends users to my website with a URL like:

**http://blabla.test/index.php?gid=abcd1234&u=bcanata&id=11472**

and I want to rewrite it as this:

**http://blabla.test/login/abcd1234/bcanata/11472**

I have created a **.htaccess** file as following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^index.php?gid=(.*)&u=(.*)&id=(.*)$ login/$1/$2/$3 [L]
```

I tried escaping the question mark in the URL as this:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php\?gid=(.*)&u=(.*)&id=(.*)$ login/$1/$2/$3 [L]
```

But, unfortunately both these rules don't match and rewrite the URL, which I can't understand why.

Comment: You _really_ should start reading the documentation of the tools you use...

Comment: The query string is _not_ part of the request URL, you need to test and capture it using a `RewriteCond`, you cannot do that in a `RewriteRule`. Take a look at the official documentation. As typical for OpenSource projects it is of excellent quality and comes with good examples: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not match against url QueryString in pattern of a RewriteRule directive. You can only match against url path ( ie : `index.php` ) in RewriteRule.  Url part after the `?` sign is URL QueryString.  you will need to match against `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable in `RewriteCond` .

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^gid=([^&]+)&u=([^&]+)&id=([^&]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index.php$  /login/%1/%2/%3? [L,R]
```